# Call different slim framework URL/REST API under the hood?

Tags: php, rest, slim

Let's suppose I've two REST services:

1) one for authentication purpose only -> This has /login endpoint

2) second for other purpose -> This also has a /login endpoint, but I want to call service 1's /login endpoint under the hood.

Sample endpoints:

1) Service # 1 POST http://service1.com/login (Request body has 'email' & 'pass')

2) Service # 2 POST http://service2.com/login (should call service # 1's /login by passing full request object, under the hood)

Ideally end user won't be aware of service # 1 at all. This is the requirement.

Is this kind of structure possible?

If not what's best I can do for this? Just simple redirection?

NOTE:- Both services are implemented using Slim Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Guzzle to proxy whole Request object (by modifying Uri) as both Slim 3 and Guzzle implements PSR-7.

Example:

```
<?php
require_once "../vendor/autoload.php";

use Slim\App;
use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;
use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;

// Create and configure Slim app
$config = ['settings' => [
    'addContentLengthHeader' => false,
    'displayErrorDetails' => true,
]];

$app = new App($config);

$app->post('/login', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $guzzleClient = new GuzzleClient();

    $uri = $request->getUri();
    $uri = $uri->withHost('domain2.com');

    $requestProxy = $request->withUri($uri);

    $responseFromRemote = $guzzleClient->send($requestProxy);

    return $responseFromRemote;
});

// Run app
$app->run();
```

Comment: Thanks it's working fine with a small modification `$response->getBody()->write($responseFromRemote->getBody());`